# Standard errors from zero vs. actual standard error value

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, standard-error

Obviously a standard error value close to zero is more desirable. However, is there a rule of thumb for how many standard errors AWAY from zero is considered good or acceptable?

Does this also change for sample size / data type?

Comment: Hi Jen, I mean in a general sense. I am trying to compare models (Linear, log-lin, lin-log and log-log) with the same data to deduce which model is most accurate at explaining the relationship between x and y. I am trying to interpret the SEs as a proportion to their coefficients. They're all between 8 and 11% does this mean they are reliable at explaining the relationship?

Comment: Yeah! This is in a regression analysis on excel. Is there a magic number as what is acceptable and why?

Comment: I learned statistics at a university not at Hogwarts, so I am afraid I can offer you no magic. Jokes aside, there is no magic number.

Comment: Hahaha that made my night, thanks Maarten.